# Filling a pandas dataframe with values from a second dataframe with some rows and columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us suppose I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
         s1   s2   s3
    bob  nan  nan  nan
    john nan  nan  nan
    matt nan  nan  nan
```

and

```
df2
         s1   s3   s4
    bob  32   11   22
    matt 1   nan    2
```

I would to fill `df1` with values from  `df2` rows and columns which exist in `df1` so that my output is

```
     s1   s2   s3
bob  32   nan   11
john nan  nan  nan
matt 1    nan  nan
```

This means, in this toy case, I'm not interested in column `s4` of`df2` to fill `df1`.
All my attempt to use `merge` have sadly failed and I always end up with a dataframe with all `nan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inplace Operation**
Use [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)
This overwrites all positions in `df1` where there was a non-null value in `df2`

```
df1.update(df2)

df1

        s1  s2    s3
bob   32.0 NaN  11.0
john   NaN NaN   NaN
matt   1.0 NaN   NaN
```

---

**Produce a Copy 1**
Use [`pd.DataFrame.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html), [`pd.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), and [`pd.DataFrame.reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html)
`fillna` won't work unless the index and columns are aligned.

```
pd.DataFrame.fillna(*df1.align(df2)).reindex_like(df1)

        s1  s2    s3
bob   32.0 NaN  11.0
john   NaN NaN   NaN
matt   1.0 NaN   NaN
```

---

**Produce a Copy 2**
[`pd.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html)
It's debatable which one you put first.  Considering `df1` is all `nan` it doesn't really matter.  But this will keep any pre-existing non-null values in `df1`.  Otherwise, you could switch the positions to `df2.combine_first(df1)`.

```
df1.combine_first(df2).reindex_like(df1)

        s1  s2    s3
bob   32.0 NaN  11.0
john   NaN NaN   NaN
matt   1.0 NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `reindex_like`! It looks like `df2.reindex_like(df1)` produces the desired result too.

Comment: In this case, it does.  But might not in contrived cases.  I didn't even think of that one, very nice!